# Find element by partial string using AccessibilityId

Tags: java, appium

I am writing automated tests for mobile application in Java using Appium. I talked with developers to create AccessibilityIds for elements and in Android it works as intended with set String but in iOS AccessibilityId contains additional characters. For example, I have TextField Name - in Android AccessibilityId is `txtName`, but in iOS it is `Name txtName`.
That is why I think I need to use `contains`. With XPath I would write

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@name, 'txtName')]"));
```

But XPath is relatively slow. How can I do that using AccessibilityId? Rough example of what I'm looking for

```
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId(/*HERE 'CONTAINS' W\ 'txtName'*/);
```

It is really important for me to use same solution that works on both Android and iOS. I prefer AccessibilityId because code is easier to understand and fast

Comment: I would think that the proper xpath attribute would be `@accessibility-id` instead of `@name`

Comment: Based on something I read just now in another post's answer, apparently accessibility-id maps to `@content-desc` if you decide to use xpath, but there is apparently a findby for accessibilityid.  You would not want to use the latter method, though, since you would need the entire id, not a partial, as you can use with an xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Any condition to check contain value for accessibility id?

Code snippet:

```
WebElement getpremiumbtn = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.refreshed(ExpectedConditions
                .presenceOfElementLocated(ByAccessibilityId.AccessibilityId("get premium button"))));
Assert.assertTrue(getpremiumbtn != null && getpremiumbtn.isDisplayed(), "Get premium is not displayed");
```